# How to select all shapes with specific color and replace this color with an other one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

I am totally new in Photoshop scripting, but I have some JavaScript experience.

I want to make a script (or find an existing one and study it) that finds every **shape** with a specific fill color in my Photoshop project and replaces it with an other one. But I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd expect a script for this to be something like

```
activeDocument.layers.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.fillColor == oldColor) el.fillColor = newColor
});
```

I welcome you to a world of Photoshop Scripting: a world of pain and suffering. While there's a certain number of things you can achieve using Photoshop DOM, a lot of functions and properties are only a available as Action Manager code, used to drive Photoshop at a lower level.

So while the algorithm stays the same — I look for the shape layers with a particular color and then change it — the code may look a little confusing.

```
var layers = getAllShapeLayersData(),
    sourceColor = [255, 0, 255], // color to look for
    targetColor = [128, 128, 128]; // color to change to

// creating a native Photoshop color object to compare hex values instead of RGBs
var colorToChange = new SolidColor();
colorToChange.rgb.red = sourceColor[0];
colorToChange.rgb.green = sourceColor[1];
colorToChange.rgb.blue = sourceColor[2];

// for all found layers
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++)
{
    // if the shape fill color hex value is the same as source color
    if (layers[i].color.rgb.hexValue == colorToChange.rgb.hexValue)
    {
        // select it first
        selectById(layers[i].id);
        //apply a different color
        changeShapeColor(targetColor);
    }
}

function getAllShapeLayersData()
{
    var lyrs = [];
    try
    {
        activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
        var layers = 0
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        var layers = 1;
    };
    while (true)
    {
        ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
        try
        {
            var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            break;
        }

        var lyr = {};
        lyr.type = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerKind"));
        lyr.name = desc.getString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  "));
        lyr.id = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerID"));

        if (lyr.type == 4) // shape layer
        {
            var adj = desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("adjustment")).getObjectValue(0);

            if (adj.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID("color")))
            {
                var curColor = new SolidColor();
                curColor.rgb.red = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("red"));
                curColor.rgb.green = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("grain"));
                curColor.rgb.blue = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("blue"));
                lyr.color = curColor;
                lyrs.push(lyr);
            }


        }


        layers++;
    }
    return lyrs
}; // end of getAllLayersData()

function changeShapeColor(color)
{
    var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID('contentLayer'), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));
    desc8.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref1);
    var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc10 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc10.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Rd  '), color[0]);
    desc10.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Grn '), color[1]);
    desc10.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Bl  '), color[2]);
    desc9.putObject(charIDToTypeID('Clr '), charIDToTypeID('RGBC'), desc10);
    desc8.putObject(charIDToTypeID('T   '), stringIDToTypeID('solidColorLayer'), desc9);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('setd'), desc8, DialogModes.NO);
}; // end of changeShapeColor()

function selectById(id)
{
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putIdentifier(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), id);
    desc1.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref1);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('slct'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
}; // end of selectById()
```

Comment: You dont call the API a DOM in photoshop. Its sort of Web only moniker. It would need to give you access to all data to be a DOM but it is not.

Comment: Photoshop Scripting Reference calls Javascript API a `Photoshop DOM` (page 32), but I know nothing about the names and terms, you might be right

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy : Oh my god, so much code for such a simple thing eh? Thank you very much Sergey, it is "working" perfectly. After I did study all this stuff, I think I see this "world of pain and suffering" to coming lol! Is there any place, tutorials or whatever, to guide me from "Zero to Hero"? Except Adobe's guide and references. Cause I don't just need a "precooked" part of code like lot of guys do. I want to learn all this stuff in the right way...

Comment: I'd recommend Davide Barranca's book on Photoshop scripting — that's the only comprehensive source on the subject known to me, including the Photoshop voodoo — ActionManager code. https://www.ps-scripting.com/ And yes, if you don't know what AM is all about 90% of this code look like nonsense, but with time you start to see patterns. It's almost like Neo looking at the Matrix but less cool

Comment: Yes I have already seen that, but the price is a bit high for a book, I think!!! Any idea how can I get those two colors on your script using Photoshop's color piker? I have made a question about that [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/125917/how-can-i-get-an-rgb-color-using-photoshops-color-picker-instead-of-systemss)!!!

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy : Any idea how can I change `getAllShapeLayersData()` function so to check into smart objects too? And something else... How do "we" know that `lyr.type == 4` is a shape layer? For example what is `lyr.type == 3` and where all this come from?

Comment: From experience :D Simply run the script on a document with different layer types and write down all the types. Smart Objects are 7 if I'm not mistaken

Comment: :D Okay I'll do it this way!!! Is there any way to declare all layer kinds and not a specific one?

Comment: what do you mean? if you don't care about layer kind simply don't use it in a condition

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy : I have add a `confirm` window which gives a kind of "report" message before start doing it's stuff. Into the `message` of `confirm` window, I have also this `layers.length` so to inform me how many layers will be change. But every time gives me the same number... For example, if I have 300 layers, 150 blue and 150 red, even if I choose to change only blue ones, the `layers.length` still says 300!!! Any idea why is this happens?

Comment: If you have a separate question ask it on the GDSE rather than in comments. Plus it's difficult to answer without looking at your code.