# How can I get an RGB color using Photoshop's color picker instead of systems's?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

I am using this script bellow to get an RGB color from color picker. Any idea how can I do the same thing but using Photoshop's color piker instead of system's one?

```
var hexToRGB = function(hex) {
    var r = hex >> 16;
    var g = hex >> 8 & 0xFF;
    var b = hex & 0xFF;
    return [r, g, b];
};

var color_decimal = $.colorPicker();
var color_hexadecimal = color_decimal.toString(16);
var color_rgb = hexToRGB(parseInt(color_hexadecimal, 16));
```

I have found something like this, `var cP = app.showColorPicker();`, but it just returns a boolean value...

PS: Newbie to Photoshop scripting!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.showColorPicker();` returns `true` if OK button was clicked and `false` if it was cancelled. To get the selected color simply get a foreground color after color picker window was closed:

```
var myColor = getColorpickerColor(); 

if (myColor !== false) alert(myColor.rgb.hexValue);

function getColorpickerColor()
{
    if (app.showColorPicker())
    {
        return app.foregroundColor
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}; // end of getColor()
```

Comment: I did a test as it is and I got this ... "Illegal 'return' of a function body"!!!

Comment: well, `return` only can be used inside of a function. I updated my answer